# Why is my html form not sending to email or won't submit when I put code needed?

Tags: html

Here is the code to my form, if anyone has a way of fixing this that would be awesome.

```html
 <form id="rendered-form">
        <div class="fb-text form-group field-name">
         <label for="name" class="fb-text-label">Name <span class="required">*</span> </label>
         <input type="text" required="" class="form-control name" name="name" id="name" aria-required="true"></div>
        <div class="fb-email form-group field-email">
         <label for="email" class="fb-email-label">Email <span class="required">*</span> </label>
         <input type="email" required="" class="form-control email" name="email" id="email" aria-required="true"></div>
        <div class="fb-text form-group field-phone">
         <label for="phone" class="fb-text-label">Phone Number  </label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control phone" name="phone" id="phone"></div><div class="fb-undefined form-group field-message">
         <label for="message" class="fb-textarea-label">Message <span class="required">*</span> </label>
         <textarea type="textarea" required="" rows="5" class="form-control message" name="message" id="message" aria-required="true"></textarea></div>
        <div class="fb-submit form-group field-button-1480832953294"><button type="submit" class="button-input btn btn-warning" name="button-1480832953294" style="warning" id="button-1480832953294">CONTACT US</button></div></form>
</div>
```

Here is the new code, I have just updated it and it still doesnt work.

```
<div data-form-alert="true">
    <div hidden="" data-form-alert-success="true" class="alert alert-form alert-success text-xs-center">We will contact you as soon as possible!</div>
    </div>
    <form id="rendered-form" action="mailto:zach@ztmartin.net" method="post">
        <div class="fb-text form-group field-name">
            <label for="name" class="fb-text-label">Name <span class="required">*</span> </label>
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control name" name="name" id="name" aria-required="true"></div>
        <div class="fb-email form-group field-email">
            <label for="email" class="fb-email-label">Email <span class="required">*</span> </label>
            <input type="email" required="" class="form-control email" name="email" id="email" aria-required="true"></div>
        <div class="fb-text form-group field-phone">
            <label for="phone" class="fb-text-label">Phone Number  </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control phone" name="phone" id="phone"></div>
        <div class="fb-undefined form-group field-message">
            <label for="message" class="fb-textarea-label">Message <span class="required">*</span> </label>
            <textarea type="textarea" required="" rows="5" class="form-control message" name="message" id="message" aria-required="true"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="fb-submit form-group field-button-1480832953294">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CONTACT US</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: The action is missing in form definition.

Comment: submit to what ? you haven't defined that on your form tag (url/action) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should send your form through an action

```
<form action="example.php" method="post">
```

It doesn't have to be PHP, but it is an example for how to make an action attribute.

Comment: You are right but the action need not be a PHP extension.  It can simply be any action that server understands, the tech stack should not matter.

Comment: oh thanks for letting me know :)  I thought it had to be a PHP file to work.

Answer (score 0):

For posting data, you should put `method="post"` in your form tag, as in

```
<form method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

The default method is `get`.

The `action` attribute is not needed if your post url is the same as the current url. in fact, by not putting anything in your `form` tag, and assuming your page is found at `http://myhost.com/mypage`, you're actually using the equivalent of this:

```
<form action="http://myhost.com/mypage" method="get">
    ...
</form>
```